# Использование константы из определения класса в конструкторе

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть класс

```
class A
{
private:
    const int _NUM = 20;
    //...
public:
    A();
    //...
};

A::A()
{
    char arrTemp[_NUM];
    //...
}
```

И сообщение о том, что this не может использоваться в константном выражении и при попытке компиляции добавляется ошибка "Выражение не определяется константой". Компилятор ведь читает из заголовочного файла определение класса и узнает, что _NUM - это const int.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально говоря, вы ведь можете переопределить, скажем, `A::A():_NUM(5)`. Так что это не то чтобы не константа... Но это не совсем константа - она может быть переопределена в конструкторе. Вы просто говорите, что *после того, как она определена в конструкторе*, она не будет изменяться. А 20 - это просто значение, которое она имеет, если конструктор ее не переопределяет.

Вот если вы напишете

```
class A
{
private:
    static const int _NUM = 20;
```

тогда дело совсем другое.